# Unable to read properties of an undefined (read 'retrieve')' error when using Stripe and React JS to set up a subscription system

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, typeerror

I'm currently setting up a subscription system using Stripe and React JS. However,

I'm getting the following error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'retrieve')." Has anyone encountered this error before? I would appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Please feel free to test the code below if you are also using Stripe.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

let stripePromise;

const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe('<YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY>');
  }

  return stripePromise;
};

const Checkout = () => {
  const [stripeError, setStripeError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [subscriptionStatus, setSubscriptionStatus] = useState(null);
  const [customerId, setCustomerId] = useState(null);
  const item = {
    price: '<YOUR_PRICE_ID>',
    quantity: 1
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCustomerId = async () => {
      const stripe = await getStripe();
      const { customer } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout.getSession();
      setCustomerId(customer);
    };

    fetchCustomerId();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const fetchSubscriptionStatus = async () => {
      
      const stripe = await getStripe();
      const { subscriptions } = await stripe.customers.retrieve('<YOUR_ID_CUSTOMER>');

      if (subscriptions && subscriptions.data && subscriptions.data.length > 0) {
        const activeSubscription = subscriptions.data.find(
          (subscription) => subscription.status === 'active'
        );
        if (activeSubscription) {
          setSubscriptionStatus('active');
        } else {
          setSubscriptionStatus('inactive');
        }
      } else {
        setSubscriptionStatus('inactive');
      }
    };

    fetchSubscriptionStatus();
  }, []);

  const checkoutOptions = {
    lineItems: [item],
    mode: 'payment',
    successUrl: `${window.location.origin}/success`,
    cancelUrl: `${window.location.origin}/cancel`
  };

  const redirectToCheckout = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log('redirectToCheckout');

    const stripe = await getStripe();
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout(checkoutOptions);
    console.log('Stripe checkout error', error);

    if (error) setStripeError(error.message);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  if (stripeError) alert(stripeError);

  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <h1>Stripe Checkout</h1>
      <p className="checkout-title">Design+Code React Hooks Course</p>
      <p className="checkout-description">Learn how to build a website with React Hooks</p>
      <h1 className="checkout-price">$19</h1>
      <button className="checkout-button" onClick={redirectToCheckout} disabled={isLoading}>
        <div className="grey-circle">
          <div className="purple-circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="text">{isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Buy'}</p>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTC8q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Calls like `stripe.customers.retrieve()` need to be made *server-side* using your secret key with `stripe-node` ([github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)), not in the client with Stripe.js.

Note also when you do get this implemented on your back-end, that [customer `subscriptions` is expandable](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-subscriptions) and needs to be requested explicitly using [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties).